# MySQL database failover/backup

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, replication, database-backups

## Current status

I have a MySQL (MariaDB 10.2) server with various databases, to which a lot of people have access to. Which means that users can create MyISAM or InnoDB tables/databases.

## Problem

Mentioned MySQL server doesn't have any serious fallback/backup, except daily backups. There used to be simple master-slave replication in use, but after numerious sync problems, it had to be stopped. I guess that most of problems came from mix of MyISAM and InnoDB tables, but I couldn't pinpoint the problem with 100% accuracy.

## Question

What is the best way to set-up some kind of replication/fallback, that would work with minimum overwatch?

One of the problems is also that size of databases is around 100GB and downtime is undesirable. If I want to set-up a replication, is there any option to do it without serious downtime?

Cloud solutions aren't an option.

Comment: "I guess that most of problems came from mix of MyISAM and InnoDB tables, but I couldn't pinpoint the problem with 100% accuracy." - We use a Master - 3 Slaves Replication without any issue, with a mix of InnoDB and MyISAM tables, and more than 100 GB of data, with no syncing issues. I think you may have different reasons for syncing issues.

Comment: "One of the problems is also that size of databases is around 100GB and downtime is undesirable. If I want to set-up a replication, is there any option to do it without serious downtime?"

Why would you have downtime. Just take dump of master in background (it will cause some temporary slowness); then set up slave separately, using the dump.

Comment: But isn't it so that I need to lock tables for the dump, so I can check binlog position?

Comment: Why I think that the problem was in storage engine:
We had few hours of downtime on slave, because of forced shtudown and I suspect that slave was in middle of transaction. So InnoDB queries were reverted, while MyISAM queries went through.
I could be wrong, but at that time this sounded as the most logical reason.

Comment: Please don't cross-post.